# Wrapping a series of elements between two h2 tags with jquery

Tags: jquery

I currently have a page being dynamically created like below:

```
<h2>a Heading</h2>
<p>a paragraph</p> 
<p>a paragraph</p>  
<p>a paragraph</p>  
<p>a paragraph</p>  
<p>a paragraph</p>
```

```
<h2>a Heading</h2>  
<p>a paragraph</p>  
<p>a paragraph</p>  
<p>a paragraph</p>  
<p>a paragraph</p>  
<p>a paragraph</p>
```

What I'm looking to do is to use jQuery to wrap the `h2` and `p` tags till the next `h2` tag: e.g.:

```
<div class="headingName">
<h2>a Heading</h2>  
<p>a paragraph</p> 
<p>a paragraph</p>  
<p>a paragraph</p>  
<p>a paragraph</p>  
<p>a paragraph</p>
</div>
```

```
<div class="headingName">
<h2>a Heading</h2>  
<p>a paragraph</p>  
<p>a paragraph</p>  
<p>a paragraph</p>  
<p>a paragraph</p>  
<p>a paragraph</p>  
</div>
```

So far I unsuccessfully managed this, but have gotten close using code from a user here (can't find the link to the original article):

```
$('.report-content h2').each(function(){
    var $set = $();
    var nxt = this.nextSibling;
    while(nxt) {
        if(!$(nxt).is('.report-content h2')) {
            $set.push(nxt);
            nxt = nxt.nextSibling;
        } else break;
    } 
   $set.wrapAll('<div class="content" />');
});
```

What I get is the `div` being wrapped around only the `p` tags but need to include the associated `h2` tag, usually the one above the `p` tags.

Comment: What's the document look like around the h2 and p tags?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Take each `h2`, grab all sibilings until you get another `h2` (or there are no elements at this level) and then reinclude the `h2` in the set.  [Here's the JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/dnt542yw/)

```
$('.report-content h2').each(function(){ 
    $(this)
        .nextUntil("h2")
        .addBack()
        .wrapAll('<div class="content" />');
});
```

jQuery Documentation

- [nextUntil](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)
- [addBack](http://api.jquery.com/andself/)
- [wrapAll](https://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/)

Comment: Nice solution. Why not just chain it all together?

Comment: Definately could, I must admit I did a copy paste of his original solution and then refactored everything but the first and last line.

Comment: +1 for answering what I wanted to but couldn't from my phone ;)

Comment: This was the solution I ended up using Thanks @Hexxagonal

Comment: this is awesome, thanks, I needed to reach the end of the parent div, you can do that with `nextUntil('div')`

Comment: This does not work if there is bare text node after header, e.g. `<h2>title</h2>some text` the some text is not wrapped.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.report-content h2').each(function(){
    var $set = $(this); // this is your key ;)
    var nxt = this.nextSibling;
    while(nxt) {
        if(!$(nxt).is('.report-content h2')) {
            $set.push(nxt);
            nxt = nxt.nextSibling;
        } else break;
    } 
   $set.wrapAll('<div class="content" />');
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/mMpVB/

Answer (score 2):

P.S. If anyone is looking for the answer to this for jQuery 1.8+, `addSelf()` is deprecated in favor of `addBack()`.

A modification to @Hexxagonal's answer worked for me:

```
$('.report-content h2').each(function(){ 
    var $set = $(this).nextUntil("h2").addBack();
    $set.wrapAll('<div class="content" />');
});
```

See:

- https://api.jquery.com/andself/
- https://api.jquery.com/addBack/

Answer (score 0):

Check out JQuery's [nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) function

Comment: This will exclude the Headline as well. This may be a smarter version of what he does with his script, but not what he wants to do.