# jQuery - select all text "underneath" a h1 or h2

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have a document with a mixture of `<h1>`, `<h2>` `<h3>` etc, plus other elements like `<p>`.

from the DOM perspective, each element is sat directly under the `<body>`, but obviously from a semantic perspective, the elements are nested by heading level

I'm trying to implement some kind of slideUp/slideDown outline expander so when the user clicks an h2, for example, I need to search down the document until I find another heading of level h2 or better, and then collect all the elements in between as being the content which is semantically "under" that h2.

at the moment, I'm assuming I'll just have to wrap it all in nested divs to make the DOM tree nesting match the semantics, but is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your HTML structure/code?

Comment: you've .nextUntil in jquery

Comment: check this answer Andy. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7968463/1551730

Comment: You'd have better to wrap it to make your HTML structure more consistent

Comment: well you can use `.nextUntil()` for that process , to select elements between 2 target elements and hide them to collapse or show them when expanding. **ref:http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/**

Comment: It's allways good make the dom (divs) tree match the semantic, and use the tags according with their semantic meaning, so... Why to avoid it? On the other hand visual positioning of elements may "fake" the structure and the semantic. Maybe you could go the wild way and find the rendering position of each element to make lists of nodes that match the concept "visually after the element X, before next X"

Comment: The reason for not wanting to nest the tags is that the content is being written by an author who is not too familiar with html markup and but is happy to use headings and p tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/) for that

```
$("h2").click(function(){
  $(this).nextUntil("h2")
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Ach3/9/)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/ says that 'Get all following siblings of each element up to but not including the element matched by the selector, DOM node, or jQuery object passed.' so it does not avoid 'make the tree nesting to match the semantic'

Comment: yes I think nextUntil is the key, although it's not the whole solution. If the user clicks on a h3 say then I'll have to use nextUntil("h1,h2,h3") but that's not too onerous. I'll also have to handle the case where they click on the last heading (or maybe put a dummy invisible h1 at the end of the content)

Comment: works a treat :) In the end I didn't need a special case for when the user clicks on the last heading because nextUntil picks up all the remaining siblings in that case. Also note that with this solution, scrollDown() will animate each paragraph individually at the same time rather than scrolling up the whole set of paragraphs as one unit, but the visual effect is fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to use any divs to wrap the elements, just use `.nextUntil(...)` like this

**Jquery Code:**

```
$('h2').on('click',function (){
       var dom=$(this).nextUntil('h2');
       if($(dom).is(":hidden")){
            $(dom).show(); 
       }
       else{
            $(dom).hide(); 
       }           
});
```

**Ref:http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/**

### Live Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/vag2r/3/

Happy Coding :)